# Asus Zenfone 5 stuck at obtaining IP address from office's Wi-Fi, but works well on other Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.3-jelly-bean, connection-issues, asus-zenfone-5

I have an Asus Zenfone 5 running Android 4.3. Most of the Wi-Fi I try to connect to gets connected to the device, but when I try to connect it to my office's Wi-Fi it get stuck at obtaining IP address.

How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

These steps fixed the obtaining ip adress error for me:
Go to Wi-Fi settings and choose the network that's causing this error. Follow these steps

1. Choose “modify network”
2. Enable- Show advanced options
3. Change IP Settings (which is DHCP by default)to “Static”
4. Now you should see a bunch of advanced options
5. Assign a new IP address >> Tap "Save"

You can check out my detailed post about this error here: [valuestuffz.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-fix-stuck-at-obtaining-ip-android-device.html](http://valuestuffz.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-fix-stuck-at-obtaining-ip-android-device.html)

Comment: It seems you're affiliated with the site you linked. Mind to disclose it by [edit] it? Otherwise, it could be seen as attempted to spam.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the heads up. I hope I have cleared that up now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it can be happen if your office use static ip. You must obtain ip address from office network admin, and then apply that ip on your zenfone 5.

You can setup it on Wifi -> Advanced options -> IP Settings set to static and then input all the things like ip, gateway, and DNS.

I hope this answer help you.